Where did I go wrong in this deck combinatorial problem?
In a deck of 81 cards (all different from each other), it is said that given any two cards, there is exactly one card that forms a "magic" triple with them. How many magic triples are there?
My approach was to assign one number to each card and then do as follows:
If I took card 1, there would be 40 pairs related to 1. For example, let's say "1 (2 50)", "1 (3 72)" ...
Then, if we proceed to card 2, there would be 39 pairs, because "2 (1 50)" forms a triple that was already covered in the card 1 step.
... card 3, 38 pairs.
And so on.
By doing so there would be 40 + 39 + 38 + ... + 1 magic triples, which is 820.
However the answer is 1080. Where did I get it wrong? Specifically, which triples have I "skipped" by following that reasoning?

Exactly one card, or at least one card?

One model that would return such trios is the $4$-dimensional affine space over $\mathbb F_3,$ with lines corresponding to the magic trios.

Then if $v_1,v_2\in\mathbb F_3^4$ are distinct, the third in the trios would be would be $2v_2-v_1=-(v_1+v_2).$ So $v_1,v_2,v_3$ is a magic trio if $v_1+v_2+v_3=0.$

@ThomasAndrews I would like to encourage you to post that construction as an answer as well. My main motivation is that a priori it is not clear that a prescribed set of triples exists! After all, they don' exist for all deck sizes. With a deck of $n$ cards we need $\binom n2$ to be divisible by three. As I'm sure you know, the existence questions of combinatorial designs with chosen values for the parameters quickly become hairy :-)

It's an answer to some question, but not the answer to this question. This might be the only possible arrangement, but I don't know how to prove it. And even if it is, the answer to the above question is pretty much the same whether from this specific arrangement or with just the general rules in the question. @JyrkiLahtonen

Your call @ThomasAndrews, obviously. I felt that it would complement the question nicely given that without a construction the question might be about a non-existent design :-)

Someone has discovered the game of set.

I think that the rules are a bit unclear.  For clarity:  I assume that, given two distinct cards, there is a unique third card, distinct from the starting two, such that the three of them form a magic triple.
There are $\binom {81}2=3240$ ways to choose two cards, and each of these give rise to a single magic triple.  Of course, any magic triple can be reached in three different ways by this mechanism.  Thus the total number of magic triples is $$\frac {3240}3=1080$$
EDIT:  in the comments, the OP has clarified their calculation. The idea is to start by counting all the magic triples containing $1$...there are $40$ by the same method used in my solution.  Then there are $39$ that contain $2$ but not $1$, and so on.  The difficulty is that it is hard to know how many to subtract.  For instance, suppose $(1,2,3)$ is a magic triple.  Then, when you are making the card $3$ list you subtract that single triple twice.  You subtract it because it includes card $1$  and then you subtract it again because it includes card $2$.  That kind of over-subtraction is hard to account for.

@ThomasAndrews  I agree it's unclear.  I'll edit to explain my sense of what "unique" means here.

Could one card form a magic triple with two (or more) pairs. E.g 80 cards and a magic ‘joker’?

@Rhys  Of course.  After all, any two cards must be contained in a (single) magic triple. For instance, start with the pair $(a,b)$ and complete it to a triple $(a,b,c)$.  Now consider $d$, distinct from the other three, and look at the pair $(c,d)$.  That can be completed to a magic triple, $(c,d,e)$ for some card $e$.  Thus $c$ completes both $(a,b)$ and $(d,e)$.

I meant if I started with card 1, for example, then one magic triple could be "1 (2 50)" or "1 (72 3)" , the idea is that there would be a total of (81-1)/2= 40 duos that are possible to group with 1 to form a magic triple. Then when I jumped to card number 2,  I would have 39 duos possibities instead because "2 (1 50)" I already computed in the first part. If then , by the end, I am left with fewer groups than expected (1080) which groups did I "skip"?

@ThomasAndrews I think the OP means "unique" - I think they are asking about the game Set. The four dimensional vector space over the three element field is the correct model.

@EthanBolker Are you replying to my comment on the question or my comment on this answer? I don't care what you guess, I can guess myself, the point is, I shouldn't have to "suspect" the meaning of the question, when OP is right there. Of course, OP might be just copying a homework question exactly, and hasn't even thought about if the third has to be unique.

@excitedGoose  It's hard to count that way.  Say $(1,2,3)$ is a good triple.  Then, when you come to card $3$, you subtract that single triple twice, though you should only subtract it once.  You subtract it once because it shows up in the card $1$ list, and you subtract it again because it shows up in the card $2$ list.

@lulu oh... there it is, thanks !

@ThomasAndrews Just providing a background guess for you and lulu. I agree completely that the question is ambiguous and missing context.

@EthanBolker I can guarantee you, both Lulu and I are capable of making reasonable guesses. Sometimes, however, and OP will treat such a guess as yours to mean "I was clear enough."

Look at the probability that the top three cards of a shuffled deck is a magic triple in two ways.

Look at the top two cards. The probability that the third card completes the triple is $\frac{1}{79}$.
The probability that the top triple is magic is $\frac{N}{\binom{81}3}$, where $N$ is the total number of magic triples.

Since these two must be equal, we can solve for $N$ and get $N = 1080$.
